# knockoutjs if and ifnot bindings are not working properly when used inside a template

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm using the following template with knockout js

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: List">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" data-bind="if: ($parent.IsFVL || $parent.AllowChat || $root.Me().AllowChatMonitoring), value: ID, click: SelectVisit" /><span data-bind="ifnot: ($parent.IsFVL || $parent.AllowChat || $root.Me().AllowChatMonitoring), text: ID"></span></td>...
```

and calling/initiating the template like this

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'tplVisitsGrid', data: { Title: 'My Visits', 'List': MVL, 'AllowChat': true, 'AllowPing': false, 'IsFVL': false } }"></div>
```

Also I've double checked the value of "$root.Me().AllowChatMonitoring" is true but both the input[type=button] and the span both are rendering. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're combining multiple properties into the `if` and `ifnot`, you need to evaluate them. Try this (assuming that `IsFVL`, `AllowChat` and `AllowChatMonitoring` are all observable - they must be):

```
<td><input type="button" data-bind="if: ($parent.IsFVL() || $parent.AllowChat() || $root.Me().AllowChatMonitoring()), value: ID, click: SelectVisit" /><span data-bind="ifnot: ($parent.IsFVL() || $parent.AllowChat() || $root.Me().AllowChatMonitoring()), text: ID"></span></td>...
```

What was actually happening before is that it was comparing 3 functions, not the return values of the functions.

Comment: These properties are not observables so your suggestion will not work.

Comment: @ArtemVyshniakov well for them to work in the `If` binding, they *must* be observables

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `$parent` when accessing IsFVL, AllowChat, etc. Try to update your template to the follow:

```
<input type="button" data-bind="if: (IsFVL || AllowChat || $root.Me().AllowChatMonitoring), value: ID, click: SelectVisit" />
<span data-bind="ifnot: (IsFVL || AllowChat || $root.Me().AllowChatMonitoring), text: ID"></span></td>
```

If this will not help, create a fiddle with your problem.

Comment: Thanks for reply, the properties IsFVL and AllowChat are not observables, the reason of not making them observables is that I'm loading the template three times with different values of these properties, so I couldn't find a way to add them as observable to my model. By I checked that other simple javascript expressions are evaluated in the knockout bindings like if, ifnot, visible but these props were not. I'll create a fiddle for this and post.